# Stresslet vs hydrodynamic force

Tags: fluid-dynamics, flow, drag, navier-stokes

I would like to understand all types of forces exerted on a small particle in a Stokes flow. According to [this](https://theses.hal.science/tel-04169741v1/file/Labalette_Vincent.pdf), page 9, "stresslet" and the hydrodynamic force were defined as two different phenomena. I do understand the mathematical definition of the hydrodynamic force. Can anybody explain the terms involved in equation 1.16 and the difference between the "stresslet" and hydrodynamic force in more detail?

If they are two different phenomena, why mathematically and physically we don't consider this "stresslet" tensor in non-Stokes situations?

[image]

Comment: Welcome to physics.stackexchange whenever linking to an external source like a PDF you should usually quote/paraphrase exactly what the content is. You mention some definitions on page 9, can you reproduce those exactly here in the question, you mention an equation 1.16 can you also reproduce that here. Other than that you should be good to go :)